# Scheduled task runs thousands of times when computer wakes after sleeping

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

Annotating a method with Spring's `@Scheduled` and specifying a fixed delay, like so:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void test() {
    log.info("The time is {}", Instant.now());
}
```

When I wake my computer after sleeping it, the task is run many times one immediately after another.

```
The time is 2020-07-14T08:00:30.358073400Z
The time is 2020-07-14T08:00:35.358969600Z
The time is 2020-07-14T08:00:40.358066100Z
...
The time is 2020-07-14T08:02:51.806689500Z
The time is 2020-07-14T08:02:51.806689500Z
The time is 2020-07-14T08:02:51.806689500Z
The time is 2020-07-14T08:02:51.806689500Z
The time is 2020-07-14T08:02:51.806689500Z
The time is 2020-07-14T08:02:51.807651500Z
The time is 2020-07-14T08:02:51.807651500Z
...
```

How can I make it run only once when the computer wakes up?

Comment: Btw, you specified a `fixedRate` and not a `fixedDelay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `@Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *")`.

When using cron expressions the missed executions are not queued.

Also, like @Lino noticed, you specified a `fixedRate` and not a `fixedDelay`. Changing `fixedRate` to `fixedDelay` also fixes your problem, but take into account that the behaviour might change since `fixedDelay` is the fixed period in milliseconds **between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next** while `fixedRate` is a fixed period in milliseconds **between invocations**.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a `AtomicBoolean` flag which indicates that the task is already running:

```
private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

And then in your scheduled method

```
if (running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
    log.info("The time is {}", Instant.now());
    running.set(false);
}
```

From the javadoc of `compareAndSet(expect, update)`:

> Atomically sets the value to the given updated value if the current value == the expected value.
>
> **Returns**: `true` if successful. `False` return indicates that the actual value was not equal to the expected value.

So, the `if` will check that no task is currently running and only then will execute your code.